# localhost 404 ASP NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a web API .NET Core project that builds and runs successfully on my hard drive (D:). I want to start working from my SSD (C:) so I copy the project from my D: to C:. The project builds successfully from my C: but I always get 404 from the IISExpress now when trying to access any of the API.

I have looked at the launchSettings.json and they are exactly the same with the one on my D:. What are some of the things I can try to narrow down the root issue and solve the issue?

Comment: How do you configure the route template? Can you create a new project in SSD and test if it works or not?

Comment: Maybe some file permission issues

Comment: @RonaldKorze I thought it is file permission issues but after I gave permissions to 'EVERYONE' in the project root folder, I am still running into the same issue.

Comment: @Rena I am able to create a new Web API project in the SSD and the Swagger page loads up just fine.